# asp.net HttpWebRequest Production Issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code that PUTs data to an api:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ConfigUtil.ApiEndPoint);
req.ContentType = "application/json";
req.Headers.Add(ConfigUtil.GetUserAdminApiHeader());
req.Method = "PUT";
UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(jsonData);
req.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (System.IO.Stream newStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

    WebResponse response = req.GetResponse();
    status =response!=null? ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusCode:HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

}
```

When I run this locally, it runs perfectly, however when I run the same application in production, I get the error

> 'System.Net.ProtocolViolationException' {“You must write ContentLength
>   bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.”}

As the code above shows, I am writing the contentlength bytes to the request stream.  Why would this fail in production (Windows 2012 R2) and not locally?

Comment: are you try to write something to response with json data?

Comment: no, just writing json to the request stream, and trying to get http response back